React Dev Tools - This page doesn't appear to be using react message on a react application
I have used React Dev Tools on other sites without issue but for my current project the extension is not opening up. The browser I am using is FireFox, the application was setup using Vite. What troubleshooting options are there for figuring out why this extension is not reading the application as React?

Im not sure about troubleshooting options, but one reason could be that you are running your application in production mode. In production mode the devtools are disabled
